# How to authenticate JHipster monolithic web applications (JWT tokens) to consuming services using CURL or other HTTP REST client

Tags: java, http, curl, jwt, jhipster

How to quickly consume JHipster generated applications using JWT tokens with HTTP clients such as CURL, Insomnia, Postman and others?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I have researched a while and found that you must follow these steps:

1. Call the authentication endpoint, the following is an example with CURL command line on MS-Windows execution (CURL installed with Cmder terminal https://cmder.net/):

   curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Accept: application/json"
   -d "{\"username\":\"admin\",\"password\":\"admin\",\"rememberMe\":false}"
   -X POST http://localhost:8080/api/authenticate

Note: linux does not need the escape `\"`.This call will return a token like this:

```
{                                                                                               
  "id_token":"eyJzdWIiOiJhZG1pbiIsImF1dGgiOiJST0xFX0FETUlOLFJPTEVfVVNFUiIsImV4cCI6MTU3OTU1MzY3NX0.B0LRZffZJuDEm17SY9xoahx-YozoNjYAbJCy-UxnqvHEHYxOXnJLFjSfymVAoBCzCnaquOFFs8iVTxBDVJeA"                                                                                
}
```

2. With the returned token you can make calls to your JHipster RESTful API using the Bearer token authentication mechanism, that is a sample syntax:

   curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Authorization: Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzUxMiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiJhZG1pbiIsImF1dGgiOiJST0xFX0FETUlOLFJPTEVfVVNFUiIsImV4cCI6MTU3OTU1MzY3NX0.B0LRZffZJuDEm17SY9xoahx-YozoNjYAbJCy-7UxnqvHEHYxOXnJLFjSfymVAoBCzCnaquOFFs8-iVTxBDVJeA" -X GET http://localhost:8080/api/workflows/1

Where my JHipster service is accessing a generated entity and REST controller called workflow and I am consuming the GET method.
The returned value of my call is:

```
{                                                       
  "id" : 1,                                             
  "name" : "mobile Fish",                               
  "description" : "Home Loan Account Table Computer",   
  "enabled" : false,                                    
  "version" : "FTP Savings Account",                    
  "creationDate" : "2020-01-13T03:44:16Z",              
  "workflowType" : "STEPS_DIFF_FORMS",                  
  "workflow" : null,                                    
  "workflows" : null                                    
}
```